# How to troubleshoot nodemon loop issue while starting the server with 'npm start'?

Tags: mongoose, server, mern, nodemon, npm-scripts

I am try to start my server but nodemon it is in a loop. I tried uninstall nodemon and install again.

In the terminal:

Start the server with the command line `npm start`.

```
mariavasquez@Marias-MacBook-Pro src % npm start

> shortflix@1.0.0 start
> modemon src/server.js

sh: modemon: command not found
mariavasquez@Marias-MacBook-Pro src % npm start

> shortflix@1.0.0 start
> nodemon src/server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `nodemon src/server.js src/server.js`
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `nodemon src/server.js src/server.js src/server.js`
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `nodemon src/server.js src/server.js src/server.js src/server.js`
```

This is my code for my server:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
const app = require("./app");

// connect Mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo");

// Liste APP
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

and my script for start

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```